# Need to configure Android libs on every Eclipse start

Tags: android, eclipse

After several years with Eclipse and Android development this combination is driving me nuts.

On every start of Eclipse the lib settings I've configured on the page 'Project/Properties/Android' section 'Lib' need to be re-applied.

After a Eclipse restart all existing projects are marked in red. For every project I have to select that project, change to the page described above, remove all Libs, hit Apply, re-enter the same Libs and hit apply again. .classpath and .project look ok. It's the latest Android SDK and the latest Helios Eclipse release. MotoDEV is installed as plugin.

This is a stupid and time-consuming process. Please, has anybody an idea what's wrong with Eclipse (or the Android SDK) or my configuration?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did a fresh install already, last time last week. I did it already so many times in these years. That future day a new tool comes around the corner that's prepared for Android development I would switch in that second.

Comment: Never had this problem with Eclipse and Android SDK, but didn't ever tried MotoDEV plugin; maybe this is the problem!?

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using and is it 32- or 64-bit? Are you logged in as root/administrator or as a regular user? This sounds suspiciously like the ~/.eclipse folder isn't getting written correctly.  We can look at this in MOTODEV Studio and see if it's something unique to us, but it definitely is strange behavior.

Update: one of the MOTODEV Studio team says this is a known bug in ADT when using linked folders. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14217

Comment: Windows 7 32bit. I'm user with administrator rights. In the past this did not happen on a daily base. After installing MotoDev installation it's on every Eclipse start now. Is it possible to use individual  MotoDev features, especial the language translation utility, without using Eclipse integration?

Comment: Wait, during the last installtion I used the folder C:\My Programs\Android SDK. I changed the path to the shortname (8.3) and all was working as expected. Perhaps one of the tools has problems with these shortnames.

Comment: We've not had problems with shortnames in the past, but we'll look. As for using MOTODEV Studio features without the rest of Eclipse features, you could do a separate install of the product. Studio will open "plain Eclipse" projects without any changes so long as only one copy has the workspace open at the same time.

Comment: Some of the Android SDK tools do not like being in a path with spaces. Proguard is one that comes to mind, but there may be others. I would suggest putting the SDK itself outside the "Program files" hierarchy and into a folder with no spaces (e.g. C:\Android).

Comment: Stupid me ;-) Having 261 chars in a path is such a new feature - I couldn't resist to use it immediately when I read about it. Thanks for your answers. I will re-install these tools on my DOS 3.1 ahm, Windows 7 ;-)